# SBT build file not recognizing "assembly"

Tags: sbt

I have a build.sbt file that works fine in sbt 13.7. But in 13.8 it's giving me a "type error in expression" error. It throws the error at the start of this line:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
{ ...
```

If I erase the mergeStrategy block altogether, it gives me the same "type error in expression" at the start of this line instead:

```
jarName in assembly := "theBigServer.jar"
```

So I'm assuming it has a problem with "assembly". Should this be handled differently in 13.8?

This is the complete build.sbt file:

```
organization  := "com.myco"
version       := "0.1"
scalaVersion  := "2.11.6"  
scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io/",
  "Scalaz Bintray Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"     // for scalaz-stream
)
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaV = "2.3.9"
  val sprayV = "1.3.2"
  Seq(
    "io.spray"            %%   "spray-can"     % sprayV,
    "io.spray"            %%   "spray-routing" % sprayV,
    "io.spray"            %%   "spray-testkit" % sprayV,
    "io.argonaut"         %%   "argonaut"      % "6.0.4",     
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%   "akka-actor"    % akkaV,
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%   "akka-testkit"  % akkaV,
    "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time"  % "1.8.0", 


    "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.10",
    "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.9.25"      
  )
}
seq(Revolver.settings: _*)

// put this in to eliminate deduplicate errors in sbt-assembly when making fat JAR
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
    {
        case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "ArgumentsProcessor.class" => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "MatchersBinder.class" => MergeStrategy.first
        case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
        case "unwanted.txt"     => MergeStrategy.discard
        case x => old(x)
    }
}

jarName in assembly := "theBigServer.jar"
mainClass in assembly := Some("servletRunner.Boot")
```

Comment: Can you show your full sbt build file? This single line `jarName in assembly := "x.jar"` doesn't produce any problems for me.

Comment: Ok, I've now included the whole build.sbt file.

Comment: Everything works fine for me, can you share your entire project?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But thanks - at least now I know it should theoretically work in 13.8.

Comment: Just try to build a minimal example. Maybe this way you find out by yourself what is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed it - it seems the problem came from the way I'd installed sbt. I'd installed it onto linux mint 17 by following scala-sbt.org's **manual** [installation instructions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html) (which actually just specify unix, and I'd assumed held for linux too.) That caused the problems I was seeing above. I then uninstalled, and reinstalled via `apt-get` using their [Debian instructions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html)  and now sbt works fine. I didn't spend any more time trying to fix up my manual installation. Perhaps there's a way to make it work. Don't know.